# Is the Unsigned Drivers Issue in Vista 64 Bit Serious?

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, drivers

I'm going to install Vista Business 64 Bit on a system I will be building.

I read a Wikipedia article cocerning the faults of Vista, and while things like UAC is completely acceptable, the driver signing issue in 64 bit editions of Vista is somewhat concerning.

In what situations would I have thus problem if I am just playing games mildly and designing using Adobe Illustrator and Photoshop CS5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only an issue if there is some hardware in your system that requires a driver, and the vendor did not make Vista drivers available for it. In this respect it is not different from loading any O/S on any system- if there is a mismatch in generation (one old, one new), there is a chance something will not be supported.

If your Motherboard, Video Card, and (I'm guessing) tablet or other drawing input device all have Vista drivers available on their respective vendor websites, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I used Vi$ta 64 since it came out until Windows 7 came out. Basically, hardware from reputable manufacturers shouldn't have any problems. By now most hardware should have drivers available for vista.

Main problem at the time were hardware monitoring utilities and such programs which use drivers themselves. There are hacks witch will allow you to work around such issues if you do have them.